# populate sqlalchemy from request.form without wtforms

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I pull data from sqlalchemy via the following:

```
u=Mobility.query.filter_by(username=request.form.get('user')).first()
```

The Mobility class has 3 entries username(string), letter(string), date(datetime). My request.form will have as part of it's dictionary

```
request.form=ImmutableMultiDict([('letter', u'values'), ('date', u'2017-05-24'), ('user',u'someone'),('stuff',u'stuffvalue')])
```

I have a header built like the following:

```
header=[]
for head in Mobility.__table__.columns:
 header.append(head)
```

I want to do the following:

```
for head in header:
 u[head.name]=request.form[head.name]

db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getattr` to achieve that:

```
for head in header:
    setattr(u, head.name, request.form[head.name])
```

This allows you to dynamically set any attribute on an object.